# how to return a list of dictionary in graphene?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphql, graphene-python

I am new on graphql and working with some datasets that is returned as a list of dictionaries.

snippet code:

```
class Player(ObjectType):
    username = String()
    role = String()

class Game(ObjectType):
    players = List(Player)
```

I'm wondering why below code doesn't work?

```
class Query(ObjectType):
        game_info = Field(Game, username=String(), role=String())
        
        def resolve_game_info(self, info):
            results =  [{
                        "username":"Malphite",
                        "role":"tank"
                        },
                        {
                        "username":"Teemo",
                        "role":"support"
                      }]
            output = []
            for res in results:
                 output.append(
                    Player(
                      username=res['username'],
                      role=res['role']
                    )
                  )

            return output
```

How I query in graphql:

```
query {
  game_info(username:"Teemo") {
    players {
      username
      role
    }
  }
}
```

Results to like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "gameInfo": null
  }
}
```

Any help would this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems in format of  returned data. Suppose, you have more fields in your `Game`, not only `players`. There is no way of including those fields in your return format.

Instead of `return  output` .

Try: `return {'players':output}`

Comment: This works but is there a way to remove the **Game** entirely? I only added that to be able to return a List of dicts

Comment: I think you are trying to define a `Game` and players for them. So why do you want to remove them? If you do not need `Game` separately, then just use `Players` and define a `game` attribute in it.

Comment: If you just want to return  lists, you don't need to use it. Just do:  `players  = graphene.List(Player,....)` instead of `game_info=graphene.Field(.....)`